# Problems with regular expression using keywords

Tags: regex

I have a string which I want to identify characteristics of flowers while there aren't special words before of them, because they change the direction of the search.

I have the following characteristics of flowers (words or abbreviations):

```
((bful\.?|beautiful)|(cful\.?|colorful)| (pe\.?|pretty))
```

The keywords that converts any feature in a "mismatch" can be whole words or abbreviations, such as:

```
((stem|(lf\.?|leaf)|(spe\.?|special)).
```

With this configuration I get the following regular expression:

```
(?<!((stem|(lf\.?|leaf)|(pe\.?|petal))([\s])*)((bful\.?|beautiful)|(cful\.?|colorful)| (spe\.?|special))
```

Now! the problem is when we get an abbreviation (features enabled) on the end of an abbreviation or word not special. For example:

### **"I have a spe. beautiful rose"**

In this case, "beautiful" isn't a characteristics, because "spe." is before "beautiful", and it is a correct answer, but i have problems with word "spe." because my application recognizes "pe" as "pretty" and it interprets its as a characteristics.

I tried to incorporate `\b` before and after of keywords, but it did not work. Does anyone know what can be done in these cases?. I appreciate all the help you can give me.

Comment: umm... could you possibly format this to distinguish code from words and fix your grammar up a bit? I'm having serious trouble figuring out what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to escape the period so it is matched as a period, not "any character". The "." without the "\" means "any character".

For instance, you should write

```
(pe\.?|pretty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you should use (\bpe.|pretty) or it might match "spe." with pattern pe. and not with spe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I got an option that facilitates the interpretation of the regular expression, writting "\b"  before and after of blacklist, and writting "\b"  before and after of characteristics. It works perfectly!! It matches the correct words.